# SubtleCrypto.digest() fails for SHA-1 in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, sha1, webcrypto-api

I am trying to generate the SHA-1 hash of a string using the Web Crypto API. The code i am using to do this is pretty much the second example from the [MDN 
SubtleCrypto.digest() page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#Example).

```
async function getHash(value, algorithm = 'SHA-1') {
  let msgBuffer = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(value);
  let hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest(algorithm, msgBuffer);
  let hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
  return hashArray.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpxe6bv1/7/) for a demo.

I am also using [this TextEncoder Polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) in Edge. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Microsoft Edge i just get the error message "SHA-1".

I couldn't find anything about this error. Does someone know what is going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

"Edge does not support SHA1", try https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner?

Comment: I am an author of webcrypto-liner, Henry is right, Edge doesn't support SHA1, it has been deprecated https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yurikasensei/2016/11/29/sha1-users-guide/. Liner was designed to address this and other related interop issues. You should really consider using SHA-256 if interop with legacy systems is not needed.

Comment: I am interacting with the "Have i been pwned" api, so it's not really up to me. The readme of webcrypto-liner lists `SHA-1, and SHA-224` for hashing. So is there no SHA-256 and SHA-512 support?

Comment: There is an error in webcrypto-liner README. It supports SHA-1, SHA-256, and SHA-512. https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto-liner/blob/master/src/sha/crypto.ts#L15-L20

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced with the need to encode in sha1, and the simplest solutions are to use this script:

```
function SHA1(f){function $(f,$){return f<<$|f>>>32-$}function r(f){var $,r,o,e="";for($=0;$<=6;$+=2)r=f>>>4*$+4&15,o=f>>>4*$&15,e+=r.toString(16)+o.toString(16);return e}function o(f){var $,r,o="";for($=7;$>=0;$--)o+=(r=f>>>4*$&15).toString(16);return o}var e,_,t,a,C,h,x,n,c,d=Array(80),A=1732584193,u=4023233417,s=2562383102,i=271733878,g=3285377520,m=(f=function f($){$=$.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");for(var r="",o=0;o<$.length;o++){var e=$.charCodeAt(o);e<128?r+=String.fromCharCode(e):e>127&&e<2048?(r+=String.fromCharCode(e>>6|192),r+=String.fromCharCode(63&e|128)):(r+=String.fromCharCode(e>>12|224),r+=String.fromCharCode(e>>6&63|128),r+=String.fromCharCode(63&e|128))}return r}(f)).length,p=[];for(_=0;_<m-3;_+=4)t=f.charCodeAt(_)<<24|f.charCodeAt(_+1)<<16|f.charCodeAt(_+2)<<8|f.charCodeAt(_+3),p.push(t);switch(m%4){case 0:_=2147483648;break;case 1:_=f.charCodeAt(m-1)<<24|8388608;break;case 2:_=f.charCodeAt(m-2)<<24|f.charCodeAt(m-1)<<16|32768;break;case 3:_=f.charCodeAt(m-3)<<24|f.charCodeAt(m-2)<<16|f.charCodeAt(m-1)<<8|128}for(p.push(_);p.length%16!=14;)p.push(0);for(p.push(m>>>29),p.push(m<<3&4294967295),e=0;e<p.length;e+=16){for(_=0;_<16;_++)d[_]=p[e+_];for(_=16;_<=79;_++)d[_]=$(d[_-3]^d[_-8]^d[_-14]^d[_-16],1);for(_=0,a=A,C=u,h=s,x=i,n=g;_<=19;_++)c=$(a,5)+(C&h|~C&x)+n+d[_]+1518500249&4294967295,n=x,x=h,h=$(C,30),C=a,a=c;for(_=20;_<=39;_++)c=$(a,5)+(C^h^x)+n+d[_]+1859775393&4294967295,n=x,x=h,h=$(C,30),C=a,a=c;for(_=40;_<=59;_++)c=$(a,5)+(C&h|C&x|h&x)+n+d[_]+2400959708&4294967295,n=x,x=h,h=$(C,30),C=a,a=c;for(_=60;_<=79;_++)c=$(a,5)+(C^h^x)+n+d[_]+3395469782&4294967295,n=x,x=h,h=$(C,30),C=a,a=c;A=A+a&4294967295,u=u+C&4294967295,s=s+h&4294967295,i=i+x&4294967295,g=g+n&4294967295}var c=o(A)+o(u)+o(s)+o(i)+o(g);return c.toLowerCase()}
```

The original is here: https://coursesweb.net/javascript/sha1-encrypt-data_cs

You can also use this: https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1